# ubuntu-12.04.3-desktop-amd64.iso installing using pendrive

Tags: live-usb

I recently downloaded, ubuntu-12.04.3-desktop-amd64.  I am trying to install it using software from pendrivelinux.com.  However, this version is yet not listed and when I create live usb using any other version, it does not work.  Is there any other way to create a live usb?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a simple way to get round this.

Rename the file you downloaded to say **Ubuntu-12.04** rather than **Ubuntu 12.04.3**

When your in the installer select "Ubuntu 12.04 64bit" and the iso should be selectable for you.

The reason why you cant select your file is a bad design by the creators of the tool. They use some form of regex to filter out files by name but do not consider the version after 12.04 - which causes they're filter to fail.